# Dynamically change App Icon in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, web, icons

I'm working on a brands app in flutter web. This app changes the app title and icon at the app launch time by calling an endpoint.

I'm able to change the title of the app, but unable to change the icon dynamically
There are alot of dart packages for changing the app icon dynamically for android/ios but not for the web

Can anyone help please?